# Flow to handle data and errors of an API in the UI

Tags: javascript, api, rest, flutter

I feel blocked in the way that information and errors should be handled in the UI extracted from a rest api. For example, a response to an endpoint can get one of `[200, 201, 400, 401, 403, 404, 429, 500]` and among others. Some may have an answer but others cannot, as I can correctly display the information obtained in the UI.

This endpoint is responsible for validating a phone number to verify if it has a valid format.

```
POST - /lookup-phone-number - input(phoneNumber) -output(200|400|429|500)

200 - {"message": "+57 301XXXXXX"}

400 - {"message": "Please verify the phone number"}

429 - not body

500 - not body
```

I know it may be a question for broad answers, but I only need a hint, a correct form for a large project, in case I have to wrap fetch in a method and have all the logic in a function or I must call each independent endpoint with an individual fetch.

What if the API suddenly returns a status code that has not been handled to show the end-user in the UI, in case all possible states must be handled so that the end-user can know what is happening, or it is better to have a general mistake for everyone else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [JSend](https://github.com/omniti-labs/jsend) format. For the call `POST /number/validate`, your API could return:

- in case of **success** *(2xx)*:

  ```js
  {
    status: "success",
    data: { phone: "+57 301XXXXXX" }
  }
  ```
- in case of **failures** *(4xx)* *(i.e the user did something bad)*:

  ```js
  {
    status: "fail",
    data: { error: "Invalid phone number." },
  }
  ```
- in case of **errors** *(5xx)* *(i.e the server crashed)*:

  ```js
  {
    status: "error",
    message: "Could not connect with the database."
  }
  ```

With this, you don't have to rely on the HTTP error codes in your front application. Note that this is not a restrictive specification. No one forces you to do **exactly** what they are proposing.